# How to load desired Latex package in Rmarkdown?

Tags: latex, r-markdown

I want to use multirow option in Rstudio to create a latex pdf document in Rmarkdown , but for \multirow to work we need package multirow. How do i load the latex package multirow in the Rmarkdown??
I tried putting codes as follows:

```
---
output:
  pdf_document: 
  header-includes: 
  - \usepackage{multirow}
  html_notebook: default
---
```

But it gives an error while knitting:

```
! Undefined control sequence. <recently read> \multirow
```

Please help me.. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work. It is important that you use new lines and indentation correctly in the header.

---

```
title: "Title"
author: "Me"
header-includes:
   - \usepackage{multirow}
output:
    pdf_document
--- 

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}p{1cm}|}
\hline
A & B & C & D & \multicolumn{7}{|c|}{F}  \\ \hline
\multirow{ 2}{*}{1} & 0 & 6 & 230 & 35 & 40 & 55 & 25 & 40 & 35 & \\
& 1 & 5 & 195 & 25 & 50 & 35 & 40 & 45 &  &  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{A test caption}
\label{table2}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{multirow}
output: pdf_document
```

(Notice the indentation)